# How to consume elements of flux inside flux?

Tags: java, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, flux

My code:-

```
Flux<A> outsideFlux = groupedFlux.map(element -> {

        //some operations that convert element to A

        Flux<Double> insideFlux = someOtherCallThatReturnsThisFluxOfDouble;

        insideFlux.subscribe(val -> A.setVal(val));
      }
    )
```

Issue with above is even after executing A.setVal(val),it remains null only(as value lives inside the stream only and dies afterwards).How do I set this value in A ?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what you exactly want to achieve but assuming that:

- `groupedFlux` is a `Flux<Integer>`
- `someOtherCallThatReturnsThisFluxOfDouble` is a `Flux<Double>`
- `outsideFlux` is a `Flux<A>`

take a look on the following code snippet, it should help you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flux<Integer> groupedFlux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4);
    Flux<A> listOfA = groupedFlux
            .map(DemoApplication::randomListOfDoubles)
            .flatMap(fluxWithDoubles -> fluxWithDoubles.collectList().flatMap(x -> Mono.just(new A(x))));
}

static class A {
    private List<Double> doubles;
    public A(List<Double> doubles) {
        this.doubles = doubles;
    }
}

private static Flux<Double> randomListOfDoubles(int number) {
    return Flux.just(100.00 + number, 200.00 + number, 300.00 + number);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set values in A without creating new A object?

Comment: You can do Mono.just(A.setVal(val))